# HTML5 Section won't span across

Tags: html

I'm fairly new to HTML5 and I don't understand the purpose of different elements very well. I'm trying to use section as wrapper and I'm having a problem of the section not spanning all the way across.

Can you please go to the following web address:
[removed due to solved question]

I want the section to span all the way across the page to cover full width. But when I give it a 100% with, it simply disregards the width taken up by nav and floats down. Is there a way to make the section span across the remaining space in the screen?

Thanks very much

Answer (score 1):

You appear to have floated it left. Getting rid of the `float: left` rule in section#Maincontainer should fix it.

Comment: Thanks! Can't believe I was being that dense. :)

Answer (score 0):

If i understood correctly what you want to span across is the menu section .. now percentage width is always relative to its container .. so if the container`s width was 900px then the elements inside if had a 100% width will have 900px

i have used this css code and it worked fine

```
section#maincontainer {
width: " put the value here";
}
```

now usually if you dont specify a width, the elements takes all the space available, but in your case you have specified a float which forces the element in a specific area, removing float will work fine